# Keeping the connection with twitteroauth

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Here is my connection function :

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
```

When a user nerver signup my app, $oauth_token and $oauth_token_secret are empty. But when a user already have authorized my app to his account, this authorisation is asked again and again although I'm using his oauth token.

How could I fix that ?